# Vector-valued function composition

Tags: calculus, matrices, functions, derivatives, function-and-relation-composition

I was going through the blog article at [Matrix Calculus](https://explained.ai/matrix-calculus/). Under the section **Vector chain rule** they did some function composition thing to demonstrate the chain rule. The example that they took is as follows

$y = f(x)$
where $f = \begin{bmatrix} \ln(x^2) \\\ \sin(3x) \end{bmatrix}$.

let, $g = \begin{bmatrix} x^2 \\\ 3x \end{bmatrix}$. Then, $f(g(x)) = \begin{bmatrix} \ln(g) \\\ \sin(g) \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \ln(x^2) \\\ \sin(3x) \end{bmatrix}$

After this, they calculate the derivative. But my main concern is $f$ is $R \to R^2$ and $g$ is also $R \to R^2$. Is function composition valid here? Because the output dimension of $g$ doesn't match that of the input dimension of $f$.

P.S.: Correct me if my logic is flawed. Thanks

Comment: You are correct, this is definitely not written out correctly. One should have $f(x,y)= (ln(x), sin(y))$, with $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. But I am still concerned about this as reputed authors have written this blog. I would really like some more people to share their opinion.

Comment: they are wrong, you are right to be concerned, and the first comment is right.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.